# How to upload a binary/video file using Python http.client PUT method?

Tags: python, methods, upload, binary, http.client

I am communicating with an API using HTTP.client in Python 3.6.2.

In order to upload a file it requires a three stage process.

I have managed to talk successfully using POST methods and the server returns data as I expect.

However, the stage that requires the actual file to be uploaded is a PUT method - and I cannot figure out how to syntax the code to include a pointer to the actual file on my storage - the file is an mp4 video file.
Here is a snippet of the code with my noob annotations :)

```
#define connection as HTTPS and define URL
uploadstep2 = http.client.HTTPSConnection("grabyo-prod.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com")

#define headers
headers = {
    'accept': "application/json",
    'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}

#define the structure of the request and send it.
#Here it is a PUT request to the unique URL as defined above with the correct file and headers.
uploadstep2.request("PUT", myUniqueUploadUrl, body="C:\Test.mp4", headers=headers)

#get the response from the server
uploadstep2response = uploadstep2.getresponse()

#read the data from the response and put to a usable variable
step2responsedata = uploadstep2response.read()
```

The response I am getting back at this stage is an 
"Error 400 Bad Request - Could not obtain the file information."

I am certain this relates to the *body="C:\Test.mp4"* section of the code.

Can you please advise how I can correctly reference a file within the PUT method?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

```
uploadstep2.request("PUT", myUniqueUploadUrl, body="C:\Test.mp4", headers=headers)
```

will put the actual string `"C:\Test.mp4"` in the body of your request, not the content of the file named `"C:\Test.mp4"` as you expect.

You need to open the file, read it's content then pass it as body. Or to stream it, but AFAIK `http.client` does not support that, and since your file seems to be a video, it is potentially huge and will use plenty of RAM for no good reason.

My suggestion would be to use [`requests`](http://requests.readthedocs.io/), which is a way better lib to do this kind of things:

```
import requests
with open(r'C:\Test.mp4'), 'rb') as finput:
   response = requests.put('https://grabyo-prod.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/youruploadpath', data=finput)
   print(response.json())
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it is useful for you, but you can try to send a POST request with requests module :

```
import requests
url = ""
data = {'title':'metadata','timeDuration':120}
mp3_f = open('/path/your_file.mp3', 'rb')
files = {'messageFile': mp3_f}

req = requests.post(url, files=files, json=data)
print (req.status_code)
print (req.content)
```

Hope it helps .