# python AWS boto3 create presigned url for file upload

Tags: python, amazon-s3, file-upload, boto3, pre-signed-url

I'm writing a django backend for an application in which the client will upload a video file to s3. I want to use presigned urls, so the django server will sign a url and pass it back to the client, who will then upload their video to s3. The problem is, the generate_presigned_url method does not seem to know about the s3 client upload_file method...

Following this [example](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html), I use the following code to generate the url for upload:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
try:
    s3_object_name = str(uuid4()) + file_extension
    params = {
        "file_name": local_filename,
        "bucket": settings.VIDEO_UPLOAD_BUCKET_NAME,
        "object_name": s3_object_name,
    }
    response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(ClientMethod="upload_file",
                                                Params=params,
                                                ExpiresIn=500)
except ClientError as e:
    logging.error(e)
    return HttpResponse(503, reason="Could not retrieve upload url.")
```

When running it I get the error:

> File "/Users/bridgedudley/.local/share/virtualenvs/ShoMe/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/signers.py", line 574, in generate_presigned_url
>       operation_name = self._PY_TO_OP_NAME[client_method]
>   KeyError: 'upload_file'

which triggers the exception:

> botocore.exceptions.UnknownClientMethodError: Client does not have method: upload_file

Afer debugging I found that the self._PY_TO_OP_NAME dictionary only contains a subset of the s3 client commands offered [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#client):
[image]

scrolling down to "upload"...
[image]

No upload_file method! I tried the same code using "list_buckets" and it worked perfectly, giving me a presigned url that listed the buckets under the signer's credentials.

So without the upload_file method available in the generate_presigned_url function, how can I achieve my desired functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In addition to the already mentioned usage of:

```
boto3.client('s3').generate_presigned_url('put_object', Params={'Bucket':'your-bucket-name', 'Key':'your-object-name'})
```

You can also use:

```
boto3.client('s3').generate_presigned_post('your-bucket_name', 'your-object_name')
```

Reference: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html#generating-a-presigned-url-to-upload-a-file

### Sample generation of URL:

```
import boto3

bucket_name = 'my-bucket'
key_name = 'any-name.txt'

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
upload_details = s3_client.generate_presigned_post(bucket_name, key_name)

print(upload_details)
```

Output:

```
{'url': 'https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/', 'fields': {'key': 'any-name.txt', 'AWSAccessKeyId': 'QWERTYUOP123', 'x-amz-security-token': 'a1s2d3f4g5h6j7k8l9', 'policy': 'z0x9c8v7b6n5m4', 'signature': 'qaz123wsx456edc'}}
```

### Sample uploading of file:

```
import requests

filename_to_upload = './some-file.txt'

with open(filename_to_upload, 'rb') as file_to_upload:
    files = {'file': (filename_to_upload, file_to_upload)}
    upload_response = requests.post(upload_details['url'], data=upload_details['fields'], files=files)

print(f"Upload response: {upload_response.status_code}")
```

Output:

```
Upload response: 204
```

### Additional notes:

As documented:

> The credentials used by the presigned URL are those of the AWS user
> who generated the URL.

Thus, make sure that the entity that would execute this generation of a presigned URL allows the policy `s3:PutObject` to be able to upload a file to S3 using the signed URL. Once created, it can be configured through different ways. Some of them are:

**As an allowed policy for a Lambda function**

**Or through boto3:**

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
        aws_access_key_id="your-access-key-id",
        aws_secret_access_key="your-secret-access-key",
        aws_session_token="your-session-token",  # Only for credentials that has it
    )
```

**Or on the working environment:**

```
# Run in the Linux environment
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="your-access-key-id"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="your-secret-access-key"
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="your-session-token",  # Only for credentials that has it
```

**Or through libraries e.g. django-storages for Django**

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer doesn't let you post your data to S3 from your client. This will:

```
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
  aws_access_key_id="AKIA....",
  aws_secret_access_key="G789...",
)

s3_client.generate_presigned_url('put_object', Params={
  'Bucket': 'cat-pictures',
  'Key': 'whiskers.png',
  'ContentType': 'image/png', # required!
})
```

Send that to your front end, then in JavaScript on the frontend:

```
fetch(url, {
  method: "PUT",
  body: file,
})
```

Where file is a File object.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `put_object` method here. It is a pure client object, rather than a meta client object like `upload_file`. That is the reason that `upload_file` is not appearing in `client._PY_TO_OP_NAME`. The two functions do take different inputs, which may necessitate a slight refactor in your code.

put_object: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object

Comment: Does this require the client to send the binary video data to django? That's what I'm trying to avoid with presigned urls.

Comment: I am not a Django user/builder, but the upload transaction should be brokered, just like with `upload_file`. I don't see any reason how or why it would be handled differently.

Comment: g_sexton is right, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46429551/how-to-upload-a-binary-video-file-using-python-http-client-put-method for an example